# How to communicate with interactive subprocess

Tags: python, inkscape

I have an SVG file with 56 objects that I want to export as individual PNG files.  I can do this with the subprocess module, but it involves executing Inkscape 56 times, and I'm looking for a better way.  Inkscape has a command line interface with a shell mode, and I have been able to export items using the shell, but when I try to do this with the subprocess module, whatever command I issue is too long:

```
import subprocess as sp

proc =sp.Popen('inkscape -z --shell'.split(), stdin=sp.PIPE, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
x=proc.communicate('--help')
print(x)

("Inkscape 0.91 r13725 interactive shell mode. Type 'quit' to quit.\n>ERROR: Command line too long\n", '')
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are providing command long enough that inkscape vomited an error. You may look through docs or just trial and error and figure out whats the longest it will take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inkscape error is misleading. The problem is a missing `\n`.

```
proc.communicate('--help\n')
```

Comment: Thanks.  Stay tuned for more questions.